# i want to find the preinit method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to put a break-point on `preinit` method.
So, how can I find `preinit` method and where is it located?
I want to debug this method and try to understand, how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following method to your page & import the System.Diagnostics namespace in the file.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

         Debugger.Break();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've ever wanted to know how something in the .NET Framework does what it does, check out .NET Reflector. Also u may find useful to have a look at asp.net page lif cycle. It shows you when the page preinit function works and what it does..